# Should I use flag or create a multiple component in react-redux form?

Tags: reactjs, redux, frontend, react-redux-form

I am in a situation here. I have to perform either of two operations: Edit a profile details or change password of a client. I can either create a component containing form for each situation above ( one component for one situation ) or can create one single component and pass a flag to render form accordingly. Which is the appropriate way?

Comment: did your problem got solved ?

Answer (score 0):

Either way you have to write code for both cases. If you are having most part of it as common and just one or two items are changing i would suggest you to choose boolean method, else if the most of it is different then i would suggest you to go for creating new component for each